# Solid background for android dialog

Tags: java, android

In android 1.6, the background color is solid but in 2.3 or later, the dialog is transparent, more like opacity 80%. So I created new style

```
<style name="SolidDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

</style>
```

but what should I put inside ??

Comment: something with `alpha`. Value 1 for completely opaque

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1252). I think you can create a custom dialog with a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   <item name="android:background">#FF000000</item>
```

This is opaque black (The first byte of the color is the opacity value, 0=transparent, 255=completely opaque).

Comment: I even changed value to #FFFF0000, but it effected nothing

Comment: Alternative way for "solid black": dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);